# Socket lose part of message in UDP

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, server

I am trying to send an image frame through a UDP socket with Python 2.7, the current frame I am trying to send is `921600` bytes `(640 x 480)`. And the buffer limit for UDP messages are `65507` bytes, so I need to split the message, here is how I am doing it.

From `client.py`:

```
image_string = frame.tostring()              # frame is an multi-d numpy array
message_size = len(image_string)
sock.sendto(str(message_size), (HOST, PORT)) # First send the size

for i in xrange(0, message_size, 65507):     # Split it and send
    sock.sendto(image_string[i:i + 65507], (HOST, PORT))

sock.sendto("\n", (HOST, PORT))              # Mark the end to avoid hanging.
```

Here is how I am receiving it in `server.py`, I inserted some prints for debugging.

```
image_string = ""

data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # recieve image size
message_size = int(data)
print "Incoming image with size: " + data

for i in xrange(0, message_size, 65507):
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(65507)
    image_string += data.strip()
    print "received part, image is now:", len(image_string)

print "End of image"
```

So I am reading the message same way I send it, it checks out in theory however not in practice.  Possibly because of some packet loss after the client is done sending - the **server is still stuck trying to read** (blocked).

I know that UDP is unreliable and hard to work with, however I read that UDP is used in many video streaming applications, so I believe there should exist a solution to this problem, but I can not find it.

All help is appreciated, thanks.

**Edit1:** The reason I suspect packet loss is the problem, is because every time I run the test, I end up with different size of image being already sent before the server hangs.

**Edit2:** I forgot to mention that I tried different size of chunks while partitioning, 1024 and 500 bytes revealed no difference (5-20 bytes lost in 921600). But I should mention that I am sending and recieving from localhost, which already provides minimum error.

Comment: *"I read that UDP is used in many video streaming applications, so I believe there should exist a solution to this problem"* - UDP is used in real time transfer of video and audio when it is better to have packet loss than to be late with receiving. But in this case appropriate codecs are used which can deal with packet loss. It looks like you need reliable transfer instead and that there are no real time requirements. In this case you should use TCP.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I realized that while I was trying to get it work myself. I should also say that partitioning into chunks makes the transfer very slow in UDP, TCP `sendall` was much faster in my experience (I was actually making live stream). And it is true that I cannot deal with packet loss, especially because the packet is a string of numpy array and I dont know how to restore(imitate) lost data in serverside. Perhaps I should ask another question about dealing with packet loss, thanks.

Comment: And the answer to that question is going to be to use TCP! It's either that or you implement something that works like TCP.

Comment: @eandersson Thanks for the advice, yet it is obvious to me anything I implement myself would be slower than the native protocols, unless I spend great amount of time to it, which is not my desire.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that UDP is unreliable and hard to work with, however I read that UDP is used in many video streaming applications, so I believe there should exist a solution to this problem, but I can not find it.

Those guys can. They design their protocol knowing that data may be lost (or even the contrary, arrive multiple times), it may arrive out of order, and their protocols/applications expect that.

You can not simply cut your data into pieces and sent them with UDP. You have to form each individual message in a way that each of them has a meaning on its own. If it is a "stream" it has to contain where that particular piece of data is located in the stream, and when your application receives it, it will know if the given piece of data can be handled, it is obsolete (arrived too late, or arrived already), it should be put aside and hope that some preceding parts would arrive, perhaps so unusable in itself, that the application should send a direct request to the sender in order to get things synchonized again.

In case of transferring an image - or a series of images -, you could send the offset of the data, and simply overwrite the given offset a fixed size buffer (which can host one entire image) whenever receiving something, and render the result. Then the buffer would always contain some image, at least some mixture of several images - or in extremely lucky cases a single, "real" image.

EDIT: an example of 'evaluating' what to do with a package: besides the offset, the number ('timestamp') of the image could be there too, and then the application could avoid overwriting a newer part of the image with something old - should some packet from the past (re)appear for any reason.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use the maximum buffer limit? The largest payload you can reliably send through UDP is 534 bytes. Sending more than that may cause fragmentation. If you are concerned with the data loss, use TCP.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17690478)

Comment: @FirstZero I explicitly mentioned the bytes size to be used for a reliable transfer :)

Comment: There is no packet size that you can send reliably through UDP -- any packet of any size may be dropped.